Karate Test for endpoint that returns an open stream via http chunked transfer encoding
I am trying to write a test in Karate for a GET endpoint that responds with an open stream (http chunked transfer). Is this possible? An example would be:
  Given url 'https://stream.wikimedia.org'
  And path 'v2/stream/recentchange'
  When method get
  Then status 200

In this form the test remains hanging, probably waiting for the stream to close.


I think in this case the server is using SSE which requires special support.
Currently Karate does not support this, we also don't see demand for it (yet).
You may be able to use cURL and Karate's support for listening to an OS process, which may be a fun experiment. The curl command is pretty simple:
curl -N https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange

